# How to apply css on sub class

Tags: html, css

```
   <main>
            <div class="first-scheme">
                <div class = "row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <p>Hello World</p>
                        <button type="submit" formtarget="_blank" class="btn-sm">Read More</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

i want apply css on first-scheme

```
.first-scheme{
margin-top: 10px;
height: 250px;
width: 450px;
background:black;
color: white;
```

}

when i try to this css but no effect on page

Answer (score 1):

This could be any number of things, but based on the code you have provided: have you written the body of the html with a  tag or is this just a shorthand way you've written it for this post (probably best to use the proper code as you would in your HTML doc)? As far as I'm aware those don't exist in HTML, change it to a body tag, make sure everything is enclosed properly and it should take effect.

Sorry if this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that it does works:
https://codepen.io/dieg02000/pen/ExWKjVr

i think your problem is you are not linking your style file with your html file. at least you add the css code in your html file inside the
`<style></style>` 
tag. otherwise everything is ok

Comment: thank you it's work but in my project  it's not work, i don't know why it's happen